# RAII in python - How to manage the lifetime of chain of resources

Tags: python

I am bit of a python newbie, but I am implementing a benchmarking tool in python that will for example create several sets of resources which depend on each other. And when the program goes out of scope, I want to cleanup the resources in the correct order.

I'm from a C++ background, in C++ I know I can do this with RAII (constructors, destructors).

What is an equivalent pattern in pattern for this problem? Is there a way to do RAII in python or there is a better way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers), which is an object that can be used in a `with` statement:

```
with context() as c:
    do_something(c)
```

When the `with` statement is entered, the expression (in this case, `context()`) will be evaluated, and should return a context manager. `__enter__()` will be called on the context manager, and the result (which may or may not be the same object as the context manager) is assigned to the variable specified with `as`. No matter how control is exiting the `with` body, `__exit__()` will be called on the context manager, with arguments that specify whether an exception was thrown or not.

As an example: the builtin `open()` should be used in this way in order to close the opened file after interacting with it.

A new context manager type can easily be defined with [contextlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html).

For a more one-off solution, you can use `try`/`finally`: the `finally` block is executed after the `try` block, no matter how control exits the `try` block:

```
try:
    do_something()
finally:
    cleanup()
```

Comment: Will it allow nesting? I don't want the caller to nest the with statements. Each Resource when creating will be creating it's inner resource. Example: __init__ of the Car object will create a new Engine object inside it. And when the Car object can be cleaned up, I would like the Car to be cleaned up first followed by Engine object be cleaned up after that.

The end user will not be privy to any of these details

Comment: @user855: `with` statements can be nested, but will be exited in the reverse order of their entering. I don't think I understand how you plan on using this, and why you need the cleanup to happen in the same order as the initialization - surely, in RAII, the destruction of an object that contains another object completes after the destruction of the contained object? Can you give an example in your question of what this would look like in C++ and your expected outcome?

Comment: nvm. you are right. I approved this as answer. thanks!